# Activation record in HLA

Tags: assembly, record, activation

In HLA, how exactly the **parameters** stored in the activation record?

I've read about the topic a lot, but
the problem is, when the parameters are any of "smaller-than-4-bytes" datatypes.

For example:

```
Procedure proc(VAL i:int32; VAL j:int16; VAL k:int16);@nodisplay;
```

(note, that all parameters are VAL)

since it isn't mentioned anywhere, that all parameters allocate (at least) a 4-bytes blocks,
I would expect k to be on EBP+8, j on EBP+10 and i on EBP+12.

But according to a few stdout.puts, it's not the case. (At least not on my system)
k is on EBP+8, j is on EBP+12, and i is on EBP+16.

Is there any resource pointing out, that parameters allocate 4-bytes blocks?
Or is my HLA misbehaving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables and parameters are stored on the stack, and the stack is allocated a fixed 32 bits at a time in 32-bit mode. Even if your parameters are smaller than 32 bits, they still occupy 32 bits on the stack.

Comment: Yes, it would make sense, except local variables doesn't occupy whole 32 bit spaces. Consider this:
**VAR x:int32; y:int8; z:int16;**
in this case x is on EBP+4, y is on EBP+5, and z is on ebp+7. And by pointing ESP to EBP+8, the 32 bit integrity still remains.
In short, it seems, that **the whole variable section** occupies the multiple of 4 bytes in the memory. On the other hand the parameters occupy multiple of 4 bytes **per parameter**. _(sorry it's hard to format correctly in comments)_

Comment: I didn't get the layout of those variables, but if it's true that you can declare byteborder local variables it's a curiosity of HLA. If they decided not to include the same functionality for parameters, it might be because it would be difficult for the caller to put the parameters on the stack if there were more than one per dword.

Comment: I realize now that unaligned local variables aren't that strange, I just never use them :) Conclusion still holds.